# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects python bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a simple program in python to do scraping. I am very new to this. I just cannot understand thing that are provided in the bs4 documentation

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url="http://www.99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid?"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
properties=soup.findAll('a',{'class':'f15'})
for eachproperty in properties:
 print eachproperty['href']+","+eachproperty.string
```

I get the following error

```
    /Residential-Apartment-Flat-in-Velachery-Chennai South-2-Bedroom-bhk-for-Sale-spid-Y10765227,2 Bedroom, Residential Apartment in Velachery
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "properties.py", line 8, in <module>
    print eachproperty['href']+","+eachproperty.string
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that either `eachproperty['href'] is None` or `eachproperty.string is None`.

You should test to see if these variables are None before you try to concatenate them together (i.e. + them).

try

```
print eachproperty['href'], eachproperty.string
```

if you just want to print them out, you will see that one is None.

Comment: Yes. It worked but please look at the following output.

`/Residential-Apartment-Flat-in-Velachery-Chennai South-2-Bedroom-bhk-for-Sale-spid-Y10765227 2 Bedroom, Residential Apartment in Velachery
javascript:void(0); None
javascript:void(0); View Phone Number
/Residential-Apartment-Flat-in-Velachery-Chennai South-1-Bedroom-bhk-for-Sale-spid-L10038779 1 Bedroom, Residential Apartment in Velachery
javascript:void(0); None` and so on..

Comment: hard to believe python can't just handle this ... java's toString()?